# SAPUI5 filter with and-operation over multiple arguments

Tags: filter, binding, sapui5, operation

I would like the implement multiple filter for the search on a table binding. The requirement is to associate multiple filter with an and-condition:

Pseudo code:

```
if(filterA && filter1 || filterB && filter1 || filterC && filter1 ){...}
```

How can I achieve it?

I tried with the following:

```
var filter1 = [ new sap.ui.model.Filter("desc", FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery), new sap.ui.model.Filter("flag", FilterOperator.NE, 'X')];
                var filter2 = [ new sap.ui.model.Filter("costnr", FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery), new sap.ui.model.Filter("flag", FilterOperator.NE, 'X')];
                var filter3 = [ new sap.ui.model.Filter("location", FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery), new sap.ui.model.Filter("flag", FilterOperator.NE, 'X')];
                var filter4 = [ new sap.ui.model.Filter("location2", FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery), new sap.ui.model.Filter("flag", FilterOperator.NE, 'X')];
                var filter5 = [ new sap.ui.model.Filter("street", FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery), new sap.ui.model.Filter("flag", FilterOperator.NE, 'X')];
                var filter6 = [ new sap.ui.model.Filter("houseno", FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery), new sap.ui.model.Filter("flag", FilterOperator.NE, 'X')];
                var filter7 = [ new sap.ui.model.Filter("customer", FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery), new sap.ui.model.Filter("flag", FilterOperator.NE, 'X')];
                var filter8 = [ new sap.ui.model.Filter("ordernr", FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery), new sap.ui.model.Filter("flaga", FilterOperator.NE, 'X')];
                var oFilterExt = new sap.ui.model.Filter({filters: [filter1,filter2, filter3, filter4, filter5, filter6, filter7, filter8], and: false}); 

                //binding
                binding.filter(oFilterExt, sap.ui.model.FilterType.Application);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were on the right track with the [and](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.Filter.html#constructor) property:

```js
new sap.ui.model.Filter({ 
   and:false, 
   filters: [
      new sap.ui.model.Filter({
         and: true,
         filters: [
            new sap.ui.model.Filter("property1", FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery),
            new sap.ui.model.Filter("property2", FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery)
         ]}),
      new sap.ui.model.Filter({
         and: true,
         filters: [
            new sap.ui.model.Filter("property3", FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery),
            new sap.ui.model.Filter("property4", FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery)
         ]}),
      new sap.ui.model.Filter({
         and: true,
         filters: [
            new sap.ui.model.Filter("property5", FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery),
            new sap.ui.model.Filter("property6", FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery)
         ]})
   ]});
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the solution